Tkinter, CustomTkinter drag widget
I'm doing a file
I know I can drop files in to my window thanks to tkinterdnd2 and thanks to this
creds: Using drag and drop files or file picker with CustomTkinter
class CTkDND(ctk.CTk, TkinterDnD.DnDWrapper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.TkdndVersion = TkinterDnD._require(self)

but I want to be able to drag a widget(label with file name) from the window, and maybe put it in desktop or in another explorer


new_label.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",   lambda event, label=new_label: self.on_drag_start(event, label))new_label.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event, label=new_label: self.on_drag_end(event, label))

def on_drag_start(self, event, label):
     data = label.cget("text")
     label.dnd_start(data, DND_FILES)  
def on_drag_end(self, event, label):
     pass


If you want a label widget as a drag source, you need to call .drag_source_register() and .dnd_bind() on that label.  Use DND_FILES if you want the data to be a filename.
Below is a example:
from pathlib import Path
import customtkinter as ctk
from tkinterdnd2 import TkinterDnD, COPY, DND_FILES

class CTkDND(ctk.CTk, TkinterDnD.DnDWrapper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.TkdndVersion = TkinterDnD._require(self)
        self.geometry("400x200")

        # note that file path is in Posix format
        filename = Path(__file__).as_posix()
        new_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text=filename)
        new_label.pack(expand=1)

        # attribute _label is the real tkinter label widget
        new_label._label.drag_source_register(1, DND_FILES)
        new_label._label.dnd_bind("<<DragInitCmd>>", self.on_drag_init)

    def on_drag_init(self, event):
        filename = event.widget.cget("text")
        return COPY, DND_FILES, filename

app = CTkDND()
app.mainloop()


thanks, it worked, I couldn't find a documentation so I had to ask here, where did you find all this?

@RiccardoZappitelli I study the demo source

@RiccardoZappitelli If it works for you, consider to upvote and accept it as the answer.
